# Cross origin request block Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i have a simple code that makes ajax interactions, it used to work perfectly about 1 week ago, but when i checked it today it says in the console : Blocking a Cross-Origin Request: The "Same Origin" policy does not allow the remote resource located at http://localhost:8080/api/user. Reason: CORS request failed.

I use firefox so i installed the plugin Cors everywhere, but no results yet.

My code :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <div>
    <h1>Sending User</h1>
    <form id="userForm">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="name"/>
      <br/>

      <label for="age">Age</label>
      <input id="age" name="age"/>
      <br/>

      <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
  </div>

  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div>
    <h2>Click the button below for getting User from server and showing it</h2>
    <button id="getUserButton">Get User</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#userForm').submit(function (e) {
        var user = {
          name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
          age: $('input[name=age]').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/user',
          data: user
        })
        .done(function (data) {
          // clear form
          $('input[name=name]').val('');
          $('input[name=age]').val('')


          alert(data);
        });

        e.preventDefault();
      });

      $('#getUserButton').click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/user'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var userStoredInMemory = {};

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/api/user', function (req, res) {
  res.json(userStoredInMemory);
});

app.post('/api/user', function (req, res) {
  userStoredInMemory = req.body;
  res.send('User was already stored from express.');
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('server up and running at 8080 port');
});
```

Comment: *it used to work perfectly about 1 week ago* - CORS has been around longer than that - you've changed something else you aren't mentioning - the fact that your server code has no reference to cors suggests it could never have worked

Comment: So, it appears that there is no need for CORs here.  The `index.html` web page comes from your port 8080 server.  The Ajax call in that page goes right back to the 8080 server.  So, unless you moved the server to something other than `localhost`, and didn't update the ajax call in your web page to point to the actual server there should be need for CORS here.  I agree with Jaromanda that you changed something in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i am going to search if i made changes in my configuration.